# Java: Superclass constructor needs preparation

Tags: java

I have a following superclass:

```
class FloatVector {

    private List<Float> components;

    public FloatVector(List<Float> comps)
    {
        components = comps;
    }

    public int getComponentCount(){
        return components.size();
    }
    public float getComponent(int ind){
        return components.get(ind);
    }
//other methods
}
```

and I want to extend it to, for example, a 2D vector:

```
public class FloatVector2D extends FloatVector {

    FloatVector2D(float x,float y)
    {
        List<Float> comps = new ArrayList<>();
        comps.add(x);
        comps.add(y);
        super(comps);
    }
}
```

but the IDE claims, that the superclass constructor must be the first call. There must be a way to implement the required behaviour.

Comment: Add a private static helper method (`createComps(x,y)` or something).

Comment: Statement which contains call of `super` must be first in the constructor of subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super` **must** be the first call in a constructor (if `super` is called).

You can simply replace your `FloatVector2D` constructor body with:

```
super(Arrays.asList(new Float[]{x,y}));
```

(and add the necessary imports)

Answer (score 0):

Put `super(comps);` as first line in your `FloatVector2D` constructor.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

"Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor."